# Angular POST Http Request make one field empty

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using reactive forms and in my forms I'm trying to append `FormData` to upload file
Just before sending the request I check my console value of form and it is correct, but when I check the network tab, that specific key which was supposed to hold the value of FormData become empty.
What could possibly be the reason ?

Here is my code

```
    // My FormGroup
    this.newGarageForm = formBuilder.group({
    logo: [File],
    mapLocation: [''],
    garageType: [],
    onCallSupport: [true],
    registeredOn: [moment().format('LLLL')],
    jobs: [],
    totalEarning: [''],
  });

    // ... Validations
    // ...
    // Appending FormData to my FormGoup
    const logoData = new FormData();
    logoData.append('file', selectedLogo);
    logoData.append('ImageName',selectedLogo.name);
    this.newGarageForm.patchValue({ logo: logoData });

    // this is how I am sending my request 

    addGarage(garage:any){
        console.log('garage: ',garage);
        return this.http.post(this.baseURL+'/addNewGarage',garage);
    }
```

Before submitting If I check my form value its correct, but after sending the request If I check from network tab, the `logo` property of my form becomes `{}`

Comment: logoData doesn't include a 'logo' key

Comment: I'm assigning the whole value of FormData as a value to my FormGroup property

Comment: please add the code sample where you use `addGarage()`

Comment: this itself is the complete code as shown in the code

Comment: there is the declaration but not the invocation of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request payload is FormData Angular will not parse request payload before making HTTP calls but if it's an object type it does stringify the request payload using 'JSON.stringify'. Please take a look at below Angular request payload serializer

```
serializeBody() {
    // If no body is present, no need to serialize it.
    if (this.body === null) {
        return null;
    }
    // Check whether the body is already in a serialized form. If so,
    // it can just be returned directly.
    if (isArrayBuffer(this.body) || isBlob(this.body) || isFormData(this.body) ||
        typeof this.body === 'string') {
        return this.body;
    }
    // Check whether the body is an instance of HttpUrlEncodedParams.
    if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
        return this.body.toString();
    }
    // Check whether the body is an object or array, and serialize with JSON if so.
    if (typeof this.body === 'object' || typeof this.body === 'boolean' ||
        Array.isArray(this.body)) {
        return JSON.stringify(this.body);
    }
    // Fall back on toString() for everything else.
    return ((/** @type {?} */ (this.body))).toString();
}
```

If you stringify FromData by using `JSON.stringify` the result will be `{}`.

So, Angular serializer is stringifying your request payload as you are sending JSON object which contains FormData within that object.

In this case, may be converting complete request payload to FormData instance would be a better idea like below.

```
 addGarage(garage:any){
    console.log('garage: ',garage);
    
    const payload = Object.keys(garage).reduce((acc, key), {
        acc.append(key, garage[key]);
    return acc;
    }, new FormData());
        
        
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL+'/addNewGarage', payload);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer,
however, I've little question, can't I do the same thing without `FormData` ?
I want my file input in property of my reactive form

Comment: if you see their code, they are returning same data(without stringifying) only when it's any of `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob`, `FormData` or `string`. So I don't think we've any other choice.

Comment: Anyways, we are converting request payload to FormData only while making API call. So it shouldn't affect your even if you use reactive forms.